Please solve this problem from Signals & Systems , u(t) is step signal?

Please solve this problem from Signals & Systems , u(t) is step signal

what is your question?  ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

you can solve 2nd question ,  where it asks DIFFERENTIATION of  X(t)

@rohitkumar As it stands we're supposed to close questions like this: We don't do your homework for you, it bypasses the purpose of it. If you demonstrate that you did the prerequisite study, and then show us your approach to solving the problem yourself and where you are stuck exactly, then we're happy and able to help you.
